# Iterating pointer to array of pointers in K&R

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, iteration

At page 109 of K&R shows writelines function written with iteration of pointer to array of pointers:

```
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines)
{
    while(nlines-- > 0)
        printf("%s\n", *lineptr++);
}
```

Question:  Can iteration be done this way only via a function call, where size of pointer to char array is not specified?

If I try to test in main(), by creating char array pointer, I must specify size.  Then when I try the while loop, I get the error message:

`Cannot increment value of type *char[2]`

Here is test code from main():

```
char line[4] = "The";
char line2[8] = "dog ran";
char *p;
char *q;
char *mylinepointer[2];

p = alloc(10);
q = alloc(10);

strcpy(p, line);
strcpy(q, line2);

mylinepointer[0] = p;
mylinepointer[1] = q;

int nlines = 2;
while (nlines-- > 0)
    printf("%s\n", *mylinepointer++);
```

Comment: If you look closer at the example, `*lineptr[]` passes the array of pointers and `nlines` gives how many. The iteration just reduces `nlines` that merely serves as a counter as each pointer is printed in turn. There is no need to know the length of each string, strings are *nul-terminated* (which indicates where each ends). There is no need to specify the length of your arrays, you may initialize as `char line[] = "The";`

Answer (score 1):

`mylinepointer` is an array of 2 char pointers. This statement

```
printf("%s\n", *mylinepointer++);
```

attempts to modify an *array*. You can't modify arrays. An array is a non-modifiable lvalue. When you pass the array to a function, it operates on a copy of the pointer. So the pointer arithmetic works.
The equivalent way to print in `main()` would be use to a pointer:

```
int nlines = 2;
char **tmp = mylinepointer;

while (nlines-- > 0)
    printf("%s\n", *tmp++);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me though why this won't work in the iteration in writelines?:  while(nlines-- > 0) printf("%s\n", *lineptr[nlines]);

Comment: It's confusing that the call to the function must be an array.  If I attempt to iterate using array notation, it fails.  (ex., *lineptr[i++], *lineptr[nlines], etc).  Any additional info would be appreciated.

Comment: The `*` (dereference operator) makes one level of indirection. `printf("%s\n", *lineptr[nlines]);` doesn't work because `*lineptr[nlines]` is a single *char*, so you can't print it as a *string* (using `%s`) whereas `lineptr[nlines]` is a pointer, points at the first string. It's probably best to read about arrays vs pointers, how they behave similarly in many contexts, etc. I suggest reading relevant sections here: http://c-faq.com/ and also search on SO for array vs pointers. Here's one [external link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c).

Comment: You are probably going to have more questions. So it's best to study a textbook and try some simple examples yourself to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm working on it :)  Appreciate your thorough help!